# Is it necessary for a collection to have models?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, collections

I'm new to backbone. I'm used to defining collections as a set of defined models, my friend, however feels that at times, collections in backbone need not necessarily comprise of models, and can instead consist of data as such, which makes them less heavy in applications. His theory being, `all the models get instantiated every time a collection is instantiated makes the application heavier`. My opinion, however, differs from his with the claim that only the attributes of models tend to vary and not the models themselves.

1. Is it true that models within collections make the application heavy?
2. Is it preferable to use collections without any models?
3. Is it okay to stick to such a pattern/ is that a good practice?
4. What are some scenarios where such a design can be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collections without models are as useful as empty arrays. They can have a purpose, but I bet in you will find yourself dealing with populated collections more often than not.

Yes, Backbone collections contains models, and yes, anytime you add something to a collection a model is created (either you have created the model some time before, or it will be created by the collection itself if you pass an hash or fetch data from the server). It's the way Backbone works.

To reply to your questions:

**Is it true that models within collections make the application heavy?**

Either no or yes. I would say no, but depends on how you define *heavy*. What does that mean? Do you find yourself crunching numbers in JS? Then go as primitive as you can. Are you building a webapp? I guess the overhead of Backbone vs the goodies it provides (such as event handling) will make you decide to stick with it. And profilers are always your friends.

**Is it preferable to use collections without any models?**

It makes no sense to me, but only the specific case could tell.

**Is it okay to stick to such a pattern/ is that a good practice?**

Yes, it makes totally sense and is good practice.

**What are some scenarios where such a design can be implemented?**

If performance is an issue, a raw array will always be faster than a Collection. You decide if the effort of managing such code is worth it.